# Keep searching for a number in an Array in java

Tags: java, arrays, search, for-loop, int

This is the code :

```
public class test2 {
    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws InterruptedException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        int[][] arrayOfInts = { 
                { 32, 87, 3, 589 },
                { 622, 1076, 2000, 8 },
                { 12, 127, 77, 955 },
                {12, 3}
        };
        int searchfor = 12;

        int i;
        int j = 0;
        boolean foundIt = false;

        search:
            for (i = 0; i < arrayOfInts.length; i++) {
                for (j = 0; j < arrayOfInts[i].length;
                        j++) {
                    if (arrayOfInts[i][j] == searchfor) {
                        foundIt = true;
                        break search;
                    }
                }
            }

        if (foundIt) {
            System.out.println("Found " + searchfor +
                    " at " + i + ", " + j);
        } else {
            System.out.println(searchfor +
                    " not in the array");
        }
    }
}
```

This code stops at the first 12. As you can see, there is another 12 in array 3. How can I make it go on, and also search for the second 12? I do not want it to terminate at the first 12.
Thank-you.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `break search;` use `continue search;`. If you are using `break`, it breaks the whole loop while `continue` breaks only current iteration and continues looping.

Comment: If you look at the code, that change will have issue with the print statement

Comment: Yes, it will, but the point of the question was how to continue search, not how to fix the printing.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code in the following way

```
   public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        int[][] arrayOfInts = { 
                { 32, 87, 3, 589 },
                { 622, 1076, 2000, 8 },
                { 12, 127, 77, 955 },
                {12, 3}
            };
            int searchfor = 12;

            int i;
            int j = 0;
            boolean foundIt = false;
            int foundItIndexI = null;
            int foundItIndexJ = null;

            for (i = 0; i < arrayOfInts.length; i++) {
                for (j = 0; j < arrayOfInts[i].length;
                     j++) {
                    if (arrayOfInts[i][j] == searchfor) {
                        foundIt = true;
                        foundItIndexI = i;
                        foundItIndexJ = j;

                    }
                }
            }

            if (foundIt) {
                System.out.println("Found " + searchfor +
                                   " at " + foundItIndexI + ", " + foundItIndexJ);
            } else {
                System.out.println(searchfor +
                                   " not in the array");
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This will keep track of every single coordinates it was found:

```
     int[][] arrayOfInts = { 
             { 32, 87, 3, 589 },
             { 622, 1076, 2000, 8 },
             { 12, 127, 77, 955 },
             {12, 3}
         };
         int searchfor = 12;

         int i;
         int j = 0;


         // this is dumb way to keep track of coordinates, but prob
         // not important to have better implementation (eg. Coordinate object)
         List<String> foundCoordinates = new ArrayList<String>();

     search:
         for (i = 0; i < arrayOfInts.length; i++) {
             for (j = 0; j < arrayOfInts[i].length;
                  j++) {
                 if (arrayOfInts[i][j] == searchfor) {
                     foundCoordinates.add(i + ", " + j);
                     continue search;
                 }
             }
         }

         if (foundCoordinates.size() > 0) {
             System.out.println("Found " + searchfor +
                                " at:" );

             for(String s : foundCoordinates)
             {
                 System.out.println(s);
             }
         } else {
             System.out.println(searchfor +
                                " not in the array");
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are breaking out of loop labeled `search` the first time you hit the number you are searching.

If I'm guessing correctly what you want to accomplish, here's how I'd do it

```
boolean foundIt = false;

for (int i = 0; i < arrayOfInts.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; i < arrayOfInts.length; j++) {
        if (arrayOfInts[i][j] == searchFor) {
            foundIt = true;
            System.out.println("Found " + searchFor + " at [" + i + ", " + j + "].");
        }
    }
}

if (foundIt == false) {
    System.out.println("Haven't found " + searchFor + ".");
}
```

If you wish to remember the positions where you found them, you use [`java.awt.Point`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Point.html) or you can write your own class for that.

You code would look like this then:

```
boolean foundIt = false;
List<Point> points = new ArrayList<Point>();

for (int i = 0; i < arrayOfInts.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; i < arrayOfInts.length; j++) {
        if (arrayOfInts[i][j] == searchFor) {
            foundIt = true;
            points.add(new Point(j, i));
            System.out.println("Found " + searchFor + " at [" + i + ", " + j + "].");
        }
    }
}

if (foundIt == false) {
    System.out.println("Haven't found " + searchFor + ".");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are trying to find all positions where searchFor is found. This is one of the way. This code does not use any labels. This will print all positions at which searchFor is found.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        int[][] arrayOfInts = { { 32, 87, 3, 589 }, 
                                { 622, 1076, 2000, 8 }, 
                                { 12, 127, 77, 955 }, 
                                { 12, 3 } };
        int searchfor = 12;

        int i;
        int j = 0;
        boolean foundIt = false;
        for (i = 0; i < arrayOfInts.length; i++) {
            foundIt = false;
            for (j = 0; j < arrayOfInts[i].length; j++) {
                if (arrayOfInts[i][j] == searchfor) {
                    foundIt = true;
                    continue;
                }
            }
            if (foundIt) {
                    System.out.println("Found " + searchfor + " at " + i + ", " + j);
            }
            else {
                System.out.println(searchfor + " not in the array "+i);
            }
        }

    }
```